# How build a listview like this in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I created this using two columns and split the list into two parts. But it got so ugly.
Any suggestions on how I can create something like this more elegantly?

ListView of cards with differents heights

[image]

Comment: Check: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) with `QuiltedGridTile`

```dart
class TAA extends StatelessWidget {
  const TAA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.custom(
        gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4,
          repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
          pattern: [
            QuiltedGridTile(2, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
          ],
        ),
        childrenDelegate:
            SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

You can decorate the way you want.

Comment: If you need to reduce item height, increase `crossAxisCount: 4,` and for this `pattern:[ QuiltedGridTile(2, 2), QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),]` needed to maintain. Check more on doc.